# Can webpack exclude a single file in a node module from bundleing?

Tags: webpack, node-modules

In my project I have a mandatory node module `/node_modules/@scope/theme`. For unknown reason it contains an example of an async function, doing nothing at all with a comment like `this is how you do async functions`.
It is located at `/node_modules/@scope/theme/build/module/lib/async.js` and this is causing trouble with IE11.
Now I wanted to exclude it from my webpack bundle, but I just don't get it done.

I tried lots of stuff with `module.rules.exclude` and `tried module.exports.externals` but that didnt' work at all.enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to patch the lib, I'm using [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to do so.

Just modify the file from `node_modules` and then run `npx patch-package @scope/theme` - it will create a diff file in `patches` folder.

In order to apply the same patch in you CI (or other devs) you should run `patch-package` in postinstall hook.

```
// package.json

"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

This will apply the patch (which is committed) when you install the dependencies of the lib.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I already created an issue for that bug on my client's other team (the module is client specific, so i changed names) to get the module patched. Since their development cycles are pretty damn long i wanted to just exclude it for now.

Comment: The idea is to patch the package in the **consumer** package, this is the purpose of patch-package.